# JPA: How to union table from different schema

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring-data-jpa with an oracle database and need to do union select from two tables with same structure but different schema. Is this possible with jpa (without using a database view)?

[image: Table from different schema]

**Update:**

Because I have lots of tables, I decided not to create native sql statements with union. Instead I use an **StatementInspector** to add the schema and create the union sql statement. This works fine if I have select-statement without where-conditions. As soon as I use a where condition, I get a SQL Error: 17041 "Missing IN or OUT parameter", because the parameters in the union select are not set. Hibernate uses question marks (positional parameters) to set the query parameters and I don't have access to the parameters in the interceptor. Is there any way to set named paremeters instead of question marks in spring boot/hibernate? or did someone already have a similar problem and knows how I can fix it?

Comment: Sure as long as the database user your are connecting with has access two both tables

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more specific in my question. How can I achieve what I described with JPA? Even a native query didn't work for me.

Comment: You must have two entities one per table. You cannot use the same entity

Comment: But the result of the union cannot be an entity.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli thank you. I'll try that.

Comment: Is there a way to use specifications for union both entities?

Comment: As I see neither specification nor JPQL support union.

Comment: Yes exactly you will have to use SQL

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following model:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Example {
  @Id
  String item1;
  String item2;
  String item3;
}
@Entity
@Table(schema = "US", name = "example")
public class ExampleUS extends Example {}
@Entity
@Table(schema = "EU", name = "example")
public class ExampleEU extends Example {}
```

And then simply query for `Example` which will result in a query similar to the following:

`select * from (select ... from US.example union all select ... from EU.example)`

This should just work the way you want it. If you have further needs for set operations, you can look into [Blaze-Persistence](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#core-quick-start) which works on top of Hibernate/JPA and has support for [set operations](https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/core/manual/en_US/index.html#normal-set-operations).